# Can't create transaction: unexpected error: Cannot deserialize mg[i]

Tags: transaction-confirmation, error-log

Have Mac OS with Monero GUI ver 0.17.1.1

Synchronised Daemon and Wallet fine (after some time)...Can receive XMR into my wallet, but when I try to send...irrespective on the amount I get the above transaction error

Have tried changing nodes etc, but no luck

Any suggestions or advise please...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error I've never seen before, and looks like a bug at first glance.
You should file an issue on https://github.com/monero-project/monero with the logs you can when trying to send again when using monero-wallet-gui with --log-level 2 (this will contain some private information relating to your address, feel free to replace your address with a placeholder for privacy).